# How To Display Javascript Function Value Into Asp.net Label Control

Tags: javascript, asp.net

On Button I have passed the value to javascript function and display in popup window.How to display the value in asp.net label control in popup

This Is My Button Control-

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSaveVisitor"  runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#      Eval("UserId") %>'  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"    ImageUrl="~/img/ExpressInterest.png"  />
```

This is My Javascript-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnclick').click(function () {
            $("#exampleModal").dialog({
                width: 500,
                height: 200,
               modal: true,                
            });
        });
    })  
    function openPopup1(UserId) {
        $('#lblUserId').text(UserId);       
        $("#Button1").click();    
        $("#exampleModal").dialog({
            title: "Business Contact Details",            
            modal: true,            
        });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use data dash attribute on the button and then use javascript to get it and display it on the label.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnSaveVisitor"  runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UserId") %>' data-userId='<%#Eval("UserId") %>'  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"    ImageUrl="~/img/ExpressInterest.png"  />  

$("#btnSaveVisitor").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var userId = $(this).attr('data-userId');
   $('#lblUserId').text(userId);
   $("#exampleModal").dialog({
        title: "Business Contact Details",            
        modal: true,            
    });
});
```

Let me know if you have any other question.